# How do I tell another HR manger that I emailed them due to the old HR manager retiring?

Tags: email, work-experience, retirement

Edit:  Thank you all for your answers and comments.  As a result I have decided per your recommendations not to email the new HR manager, but I will mention this work experience if I am lucky enough for an interview.  I've always wanted this position which is very rarely advertised, and have worked extremely hard to gain the experience necessary, so I really appreciate everyone's help in regards to this!

---

Three years ago I performed work experience for a large company based out of the USA.  The HR manager at the time helped me organize this work experience and mentioned to me that 'she looks forward to seeing my application in the future'.

I have been building my experience ever since, and have just found out that the position I have always wanted has been advertised.  However, I have just found out via a press release that a **new HR manager** has taken over her, as the old HR manager who helped me organize this work experience has since retired.

I am wanting to send a follow up email to the new HR manager mentioning my previous work experience organized by the old HR manager, but I would like to explain why I am sending the email to him.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

> I wanted to send this email to you as I understand that Ms. XXXX has since retired, ***and you are the new HR manager***. I have been watching for opportunities to arise at XXX since this work experience placement.........

I've also though of using the sentence 'and you have since taken over her position'.  However both sentences including the part in bold/italics seems a bit rude.  Is there any better way that this can be explained to the new HR manager on why the email is now going to him?

Thank you again for your assistance!  Really appreciate it.

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this? Are you expecting to have better chance of landing a job by emailing the new HR manager?

Comment: Good Question.  Whilst I understand that name dropping won't work, I am intending on asking for a recommendation in regards to my application, OR Alternatively, some advice on the recruitment process at XXXX would be of great help.  
 @Twyxz

Comment: Very rarely HR will give you an edge against other applicants simply because you asked for it. Having work experience as it is will give you this extra boost however you may want to mention it in your interview

Comment: List the old HR manager as reference if it is OK with them and follow the standard application process.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've decided against emailing the new HR manager and hence edited my question above to explain.  Thank you again~

Comment: @DebbieWilliams Make sure you have it in your application too

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need to say is in your question above.  Make it very clear on your application that you did your work experience there and how much you enjoyed it and that since then, you've been gaining the necessary experience for this role that you're now applying for

The new HR person can easily find your file and any comments by their predecessor and can tell by your application whether or not you're a suitable fit.  I don't see how knowing someone who used to work there is going to help you at all.